# Can I trust these microwave power readings?

Tags: microwave, waveguide

So I've got an old Hughes TWT that supplies roughly 20W across the Ku band (12.4 - 18 GHz) that has a waveguide output flange (WR-62). I am "gently re-purposing" it to be driven at a lower frequency (11 GHz) and running the power through a series of WR-62 directional couplers to measure the actual power output via some N-type coax adapters and power sensors.

11 GHz is clearly above the cutoff frequency for WR-62, but I am getting some strange power readings. I expect that from the amplifier; I'm not surprised that the gain or saturated output varies a lot once you get out of band. What's surprising is that the power output is reading higher than what the amplifier produces in band - from 40-60 watts! I'm fairly confident that I have the offset on the power sensors correct. Any idea what could be happening here? I'm fairly certain the output is not actually 40-60. For context we see around 30 watts at the lowest "known good frequency" (12.4 GHz).

My best guess was that we might have some non-fundamental modes in the waveguide that make the area where the coax transition probe penetrates the waveguide read higher. Just curious what any folks with WG / TWT experience think about this.

Comment: Know any good jokes?  How's "Fang?" :)

Comment: @JRE Assuming we're talking about the same guy, he's invented his own unit system and I have to lock up the power tools when he's around. Par for the course, I think!

Comment: "Fang" was Phyllis Diller's fictional husband.

Comment: Shucks. I'm clearly too young for this name.

Comment: can you hook the system up to a dummy load to figure out the power it is actually putting out?

Comment: @JorenVaes All the dummy loads I've ever seen are just heatsinks. I'm not sure how it would provide a better measurement. Are you thinking about calorimetry, ala running water through a load and measuring the before and after temp?

Comment: I think the "dummy load" idea is to provide a more controlled VSWR.